# Help on reverse engineering a game stat calculation

Tags: percentages

i hope you're all doing fine, and thanks you for passing by and read my question

I'm doing a reverse engineering of a soccer game stats hexagon (PES games) i manage to figure it that there are two values that affect the position of one of the 6 edges but i can't to the right equation to get the value

so lets say the result value should be between 0 and 100 and the receiving values are between 1 and 99

The stat are ATTACK and SHOT ACCURACY, by changing them with the max and min values i notice this

if ATTACK is 99 and SHOT ACCURACY is 1 then the edge gets to 50
if ATTACK is 1 and SHOT ACCURACY is 99 then the edge gets to 1
if both are 1 then the edge gets to 0
if both are 99 then the edge gets to 100

what kind of ecuation should i use to get this values?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with multiple linear regression with an interaction term. If ATTACK is $x$, SHOT ACCURACY is $y$, and the edge is $z$, then the equation is
$$z=ax+by+cxy+d$$
with $a,b,c,d$ some parameters.
You gave 4 equations and those uniquely determine the values $a,b,c,d$:
$$a=\frac{99}{196}\\
b=\frac{1}{196}\\ c=\frac{1}{196}\\d=-\frac{101}{196}\\
$$

Comment: Logistical regression could also make sense here (look it up).

Comment: Thanks a lot Anton!!! I will also check Logistical regression!